How to override SolidColorBrush resource defined in a Style?
How to cover SolidColorBrush out of ResourceDictionary in WPF?
ButtonStyle1.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor" Color="LightGreen" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" />
    
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor}">Hello World</TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>    
</ResourceDictionary>

ButtonWindow.xaml
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyle1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor" Color="LightSkyBlue"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="68" Width="159"/>

    </Grid>

I want to cover the color with LightSkyBlue, but it failed. How can do it? Thanks.

Try to use {DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColor} in the template, instead of {StaticResource....
